# regex split on uppercase, but ignore titlecase

Tags: python, regex

How can I split `This Is ABC Title` into `This Is, ABC, Title` in Python? If is use `[A-Z]` as regex expression it will be split into `This, Is, ABC, Title`? I do not want to split on whitespace.

Comment: Perhaps `re.split(r'\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*', text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.split(r'\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*', text)
```

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - word boundary
- `([A-Z]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more ASCII uppercase letters
- `\b` - word boundary([A-Z]+)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

Note the use of capturing group that makes `re.split` also output the captured substring.

See the Python demo:

```py
import re
text = "This Is ABC Title"
print( re.split(r'\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*', text) )
# => ['This Is', 'ABC', 'Title']
```